# formidable is not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multipartform-data, formidable

I am using formidable package to parse a form in node.js to upload a file. When i trying to triggering form.parse() method it is not working properly.

This is my server side code.

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
http = require('http'),
util = require('util');
console.log("Before parsing");
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
console.log(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
});
return;
```

Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Where is your request handler? Where does `req` come from?

Comment: Is this all your code?  Do you have this wrapped in a server?  Where is the req defined?  If not you may want to look at the example at [Formidable Example](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#example).

Comment: Its small piece of code which is inside a function. The function is recieving the both req and res. no problem due to req and res it seems.